# Saving image as JPG -library?

Tags: c++, windows, jpeg

I'd like to find a JPEG-writing library that can be statically linked (so there are no DLL dependencies). No JPEG-reading ability is required.

**Edit:** I got LibGD working, but it had one problem described here:

[LibGD library is not working: crash when saving image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307965/libgd-library-is-not-working-crash-when-saving-image)

Comment: Sorry, I only know libraries that can save *and* load jpegs.  Like GDI+, available on Windows since at least XP.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling SaveJPG(), ignore the example on the top of that page. Look for // Writing Usage in Jpegfile.cpp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [LibGD](http://www.libgd.org/Main_Page)? I can't seem to find the license, but neither did you specify a requirement.

Comment: GD seems to be under its own licence, which is similar to the ISC licence. Of course, actually read the licence to know what your obligations are. :-)

Answer (score 3):

[libjpeg](http://www.ijg.org/) is the most popular library for saving jpegs, but it can be a bit of a pain to use.

Edit, here is a [simple example](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#c8wBSCe9-BE/sources/juce_1_29.zip%7C-4XTvqhbhDY/juce/src/juce_appframework/gui/graphics/imaging/image_file_formats/juce_JPEGLoader.cpp&q=juce_writeJPEGImageToStream) of how to use it. Look for the function juce_writeJPEGImageToStream.

Comment: can you send the .lib file download link too, i cant compile that

Answer (score 1):

If you're running your application on Windows then you should use the standard, built-in "GDI+" library that Microsoft provides.  Every computer running XP or later has this library.

GDI+ is intended to supersede GDI, which is what you're probably already using whether you know it or not, but it can co-exist with GDI calls provided you flush the buffers when switching between the two.  See:

http://www.cpjj.net/Miscellaneous/CreateJPEGFromDC.htm

(Hans Passant - you should have written your comment as an answer).